# How to open dropdown control(html) without mouse click and using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

it is possible to open drop down list without mouse click and using pure JavaScript ?

Comment: Typically you want to include some example code of what you've tried and what isn't working. In the future, make sure you've given it a good-faith effort before asking a question. :)

Comment: Could you specify whether you mean a `<select>` or a dropdown menu for navigation links?

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you mean a dropdown nav menu, not a `<select>`.

```
 <ul>
    <li><a>hover here</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

css:

```
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/InuVirOp/1/edit)

Comment: How is an unordered list a drop-down list?

Comment: @Joe Simmons, this is a common way to make "drop-down lists" using CSS, particularly for things like nav bars.

Comment: Does he mean "select". That question is terribly unclear, then. Dropdown menu's are made with lists (ul li) so...why shouldn't I expect this to be a good answer?

Comment: Ah, I see now that you edited the code. Not bad.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but is not possible. Best thing you could get is select a option from the list.